# Socketio: Error: Lone surrogate U+D83D is not a scalar value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

recently my node.js server has been crashing a lot due to this `socket.io` error. My suspicion is that client is sending invalid utf string, which will throw an error in the `utf8.js` file. Is there a way to avoid server crash? It's very frustrating. I'm down to monkey patch this file if needed.

```
Error: Lone surrogate U+D83D is not a scalar value
at Error (native)
at checkScalarValue (/root/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/utf8.js:69:10)
at encodeCodePoint (/root/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/utf8.js:90:4)
at Object.utf8encode [as encode] (/root/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/engine.io-parser/node_modules/utf8/utf8.js:111:18)
at Object.exports.encodePacket (/root/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/engine.io-parser/lib/index.js:74:34)
at encodeOne (/root/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/engine.io-parser/lib/index.js:387:13)
at eachWithIndex (/root/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/engine.io-parser/lib/index.js:256:5)
at map (/root/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/engine.io-parser/lib/index.js:263:5)
at Object.exports.encodePayloadAsBinary (/root/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/engine.io-parser/lib/index.js:411:3)
at Object.exports.encodePayload (/root/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/engine.io-parser/lib/index.js:225:20)
at XHR.Polling.send (/root/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/lib/transports/polling.js:238:10)
at Socket.flush (/root/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/lib/socket.js:341:20)
at Socket.sendPacket (/root/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/lib/socket.js:317:10)
at Socket.send.Socket.write (/root/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/lib/socket.js:290:8)
at writeToEngine (/root/node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js:148:17)
at Client.packet (/root/node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js:159:7)
```

Comment: Do you have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Checkout this [#2820 issue on github](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2820)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying to send your data in some wrong way.

You could try to have a `try {} catch (e) {}` around your Client/socket.packet, or do something like this:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  console.log(`Caught exception: ${err}`);
});
```

To prevent the server from dieing.